# stacktrace optimization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 64-bit, stack-trace

In my C# application, I have used stacktrace to capture method name and file name in case of failure.

There is some difference in the stacktrace between x86 and x64 platforms.

```
public string ErrorMessage
    {
      set
        {
         _strErrorMessage = "Error : " + value;
         //Call the method to log error.
         LogError(value);
        }
    }
```

In the above code snippet, while setting the ErrorMessage property, I am calling the LogError method, which is capturing the stack trace and writing it into the log file.

```
MethodA()
 {
   Logger obj=new Logger();
   obj.ErrorMessage="Failure";
 }
```

In this case, on the x86 platform, the stack trace contains two stackframes. One for methodA and another for the setter of the ErrorMessage property.

On the x64 platform, the stack trace contains only one stackframe for methodA and there is no stackframe for the setter of the ErrorMessage property.

Can anybody explain to me how the optimization is happening while getting the stacktrace?

Comment: Where is `MethodA` getting called? This code isn't complete.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/6aa690fc-d2f4-4d04-9dca-cf9d5a445724

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any difference between x64 and x86 output when I try getting the stack trace output in a test-harness. (I wasn't expecting to, but I always want to challenge my assumptions!).

The only time I would expect to see a difference in the call stack is when you're compiling the code in **release** mode. When you do this, the JITter will often in-line simple method calls, e.g. the setter of your property. (Yes, if you reflect on your release-mode code, you **will** still see the separate methods; it's only when the method is JITted that you'll see this difference)

What this means to you is that in debug, the setter will appear in the call stack:

```
   at ConsoleApplication5.Program.set_ErrorMessage(String value)
   at ConsoleApplication5.Program.MethodA()
   at ConsoleApplication5.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

But when you compile it in release mode, the code within set_ErrorMessage will be inlined into MethodA, meaning that you'll only see this:

```
   at ConsoleApplication5.Program.MethodA()
   at ConsoleApplication5.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This optimization is configurable in the project properties on the Build tab. When you switch between Debug and Release in the Configuration dropdown you'll see a difference in the "Optimize code" checkbox. Yes, you could turn off compiler optimizations for release builds, but then you'd be potentially hampering the performance of your application, which I wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that on x64 the JIT is inlining (optimizing) more aggressively. Try doing the following to see if that's the case or just run in Debug mode, where optimizations that impact debugging should be turned off:

```
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
      [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
      set
        {
         _strErrorMessage = "Error : " + value;
         //Call the method to log error.
         LogError(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like a reasonable theory. The 64-bit JITter often does things differently from the 32-bit JITter, right down to the decisions it makes whether or not to inline method calls.